# MC/DC coverage tools for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have recently took the CS258 free online course, and it mentioned a code coverage called the MC/DC coverage, which is used in embedded software, such as computers on cars, planes, etc...

but I couldn't find a free tool to show me MC/DC coverage for my program, are there any recommendations?

Comment: @AndersK I have googled, and these links are either broken or is a commercial software, I'm searching for a freeware. I know that sqllite's core has a 100% MC/DC Coverage, but it said it was done by gcov, in my memory, gcov can only provide statment coverage and branch coverage data.

Comment: The MC/DC coverage criterion is used in **critical** embedded software. Most embedded software does not justify its application. That is part of the reason it will difficult for you to find a free tool to measure it. The other part is that measuring MC/DC coverage requires heavier instrumentation than simpler coverage criteria.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Umm... that is a problem, but how did sqllite did it's 100% MC/DC coverage? with gcov? btw, what does most embedded software does not justify its application actually mean? does that mean most embedded softwares don't do unit test, don't do code coverage testing, or they don't test? I'm working on an embedded software, and we don't have unit test, cause it's kind of tricky to do that in the real enviournment

Comment: - How did sqlite ...? I don't know, ask them.

Comment: - what does most embedded software does not justify its application actually mean -> it means that achieving MC/DC coverage takes a lot of tests; tests are expensive to write. And MC/DC requires justifications (some conditions cannot be enabled independently. In this case it is impossible to write the testcase, but it must be justified that the conditions are not independent). Non-critical software would be considered to have been tested if statement coverage was achieved, I think.

Comment: gcov doesn't do MC/DC, to my understanding.  You need a more sophisticated scheme to capture coverage data.

Comment: The bit about "most embedded software doesn't justify it (MC/DC)" I think is inappropriate.  It is true that it is hard to get good tests and therefore coverage, and harder to get full coverage for MC/DC than simple branch coverage.    That's doesn't mean I shouldn't expect my supplier to do the best testing and checking that the economics justify.  And too often the fact that the product isn't critical is used as justification for lousy testing.  Our society is worse for this.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that Project Coverage (now called [Project Couverture](http://www.open-do.org/projects/couverture/)) will probably be the first good answer to the question of non-invasive AND open-source coverage analysis. Their latest code release is [currently here](https://forge.open-do.org/scm/?group_id=8) and a *mile-high* kind of project presentation can [be seen here](http://libre.adacore.com/uploads/project_coverage.pdf).

As to how SQLite claims MC/DC coverage using just `gcov`, they base this on the fact that in C, the logic AND and OR follow short-circuit evaluation; meaning that in any boolean expression comparisons...

```
if (((A == B) || (C != D)) && (E != F)) ...
```

...C will, by definition, stop evaluating at the first expression that 'decides' the whole; so if A is equal to B, the decision-making is already done - if not, it continues to the next expression, and so on. This means that the MC/DC requirement...

```
Each condition in a decision must be shown to *independently*
          affect the outcome of the decision
```

...is sort of "covered by default".

There is an exception to that, though - read their [explanation](https://www.sqlite.org/testing.html#branch_coverage_versus_mc_dc) here.

Comment: There is a good explanation of this by NASA as well (in the downloadable MC/DC slides): https://nescacademy.nasa.gov/video/a0662ba57c124317ba755d67c3d7d37b1d

Comment: [Modified Condition and Decision Coverage in Gcc: Intro, Motivation & Tooling - Jørgen Kvalsvik](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSFlLgxXHqs) gave a good explaination regarding to branch coverage, decision coverage and MC/DC coverage, too. From the examples shown start from 16:40, it seems to me MC/DC coverage is not sort of "covered by default" with branch coverage.